# how to run perl regex command remotely

Tags: shell, regex, perl

I got this command that works perfectly on the remote server

```
perl -ne 'print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /^[^\[]*\[\K([^]]+)[^{]*{[^[]*\["\K([^"]+)(?:(?!SmsJob).)*SmsJob:\K([0-9a-f]+)/' /path/to/file.log
```

but then when I try to run it locally by saving it as a [shell function](https://superuser.com/a/1291716/234141) like so:

```
function getRemoteLogs()
{
    ssh -i $ssh_key_file ubuntu@$1 -t 'perl -ne `print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /^[^\[]*\[\K([^]]+)[^{]*{[^[]*\["\K([^"]+)(?:(?!SmsJob).)*SmsJob:\K([0-9a-f]+)/` /path/to/file.log' > local.txt
}
```

where `$1` is the ip of the remote server

it returns this error:

```
bash: command substitution: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: command substitution: line 0: `print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /^[^\[]*\[\K([^]]+)[^{]*{[^[]*\["\K([^"]+)(?:(?!SmsJob).)*SmsJob:\K([0-9a-f]+)/'
Unknown regexp modifier "/w" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/w" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/w" at -e line 1, at end of line
syntax error at -e line 1, near "18.log
"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

how do I do this?

Comment: \` has a totally different meaning to `'`.

Comment: great! and so now do I use `'` properly instead of `?

Comment: this isn't working     `ssh -i $ssh_key_file ubuntu@$1 -t 'perl -ne \'print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /^[^\[]*\[\K([^]]+)[^{]*{[^[]*\["\K([^"]+)(?:(?!SmsJob).)*SmsJob:\K([0-9a-f]+)/\' /var/www/toters/storage/logs/info-2019-02-18.log' > local.txt`

Comment: You can't escape `'` inside a `'`. You need to end the outer quotes, escape the quote, and start the quotes again.

Answer (score 1):

The backticks you are using tell Perl to pass everything inside them to the underlying shell as a command - like exec or system() would do.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)'s a link that discusses backticks in Perl.

You do need to quote the whole perl command for the remote server, but you will have to use double quotes. Then you must escape the inner double quotes and the variables that would otherwise expand.

Try this out:

```
ssh -i $ssh_key_file ubuntu@<remote ip> "perl -ne 'print \"\$1,\$2,\$3\n\" if /^[^\[]*\[\K([^]]+)[^{]*\{[^[]*\[\"\K([^\"]+)(?!SmsJob).)*SmsJob:\K([0-9a-f]+)/' /path/to/file.log" > local.txt
```

I also escaped the left brace after the glob, because perl complained about it.

Also, I don't think you need to force a pseudo tty on the connection, so you can probably drop `-t`. If that gives you trouble then I would try it with `-T` first to disable pseudo TTY creation.

Comment: You _do_ need to quote the whole command, as SSH does not preserve individual arguments – it just concatenates them and the result is used as a single argument for `/bin/sh -c "..."` (similarly to how 'eval' works). The remote side wouldn't know that the part after `-ne` had been single-quoted locally.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that correction.  But he could use double quotes, right? That way he could have the single quotes preserved in the command.  I am finally at a computer now, so I will do some testing on this.

Comment: Yes, but the _inner_ double quotes and the Perl $variables would need to be backslash-escaped in addition to that.

Comment: Sure, that is what I was about to check.  After I do this actual testing I'll edit my answer above.  Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: My initial reason for not wanting double quotes was actually having to escape the regex captures in that print command. haha

Comment: Trick for bash 5.0 and later: `cmd=(perl -ne 'print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /someregex/' /path/to/file.log); ssh $host "${cmd[*]@Q}"`

Comment: @grawity nice tip there.  I doubt he has bash 5.0 if he is using Ubuntu though.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of alternatives to Guy's answer.

I shortened your original command to make it (slightly) more readable:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /^([^\[]*)(?:.*(?!SmsJob).)*/' /var/log/syslog
```

Now with `ssh`, if you put the perl code in double-quotes, you could use `qq{}` inside, instead of escaped double-quotes. However, you would still need to escape the `$` variables:

```
ssh -i $id $user@$host 'perl -ne "print qq{\$1,\$2,\$3\n} if /^([^\[]*)(?:.*(?!SmsJob).)*/" /var/log/syslog'
```

A more readable alternative is to use the suggestion in @choroba's comment: close and reopen the quotes:

```
ssh -i $id $user@$host 'perl -ne ' "'" 'print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /^([^\[]*)(?:.*(?!SmsJob).)*/' "'" /var/log/syslog
```

or slightly shorter by keeping the first part in double-quotes:

```
ssh -i $id $user@$host "perl -ne '" 'print "$1,$2,$3\n" if /^([^\[]*)(?:.*(?!SmsJob).)*/' "'" /var/log/syslog
```

(tested with a local Ubuntu 16.04, and a remote Debian 9)